# Having problems with JSplitPane in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have just started learning swing in Java. I'm having problems with JSplitPane in swing library. I have made an app that has four classes `Frame(), TablePanel(), TextPanel(), FormPanel()` Frame is the main class which extends JFrame.The following image describes these classes more clearly.

[image]

now my problem is that I want the spliter to be between `TablePanel` class and `TextPanel` class. I was wondering if there was a way that in `TablePanel` I instantiate `TextPanel` and set spliter between Table Panel and `TextPanel` something like :

The following is just a pseudocode;

```
TablePanel() {
TextPanel textPanel = new TextPanel();
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JSplitPane spliter = new JSplitPane(vertical, textPanel, this);

add(spliter);
}
```

Please if I'm wrong. Correct my mistake by suggesting a better way.

An helpful answer will be appreciated. Thank in advance!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#JSplitPane%28int,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Component%29): `public JSplitPane(int newOrientation, Component newLeftComponent, Component newRightComponent)` with `newOrientation - JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT or JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT`. However, I am not 100% sure about your question.

Comment: Actually I know that as I mentioned its a pseudocode not actual code. I just want to convey the idea of the result I want. I want to know that can I pass `TablePanel` to `JSplitPane` inside `TablePanel` constructor. As I did in my question by adding `this`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  (I.E. a working example, not uncompilable code snippets or pseudo-code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSplitPane.setDividerLocation(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation-double-), but note the Java Docs:

> Sets the divider location as a percentage of the `JSplitPane`'s size.
>
> This method is implemented in terms of `setDividerLocation(int)`. This method immediately changes the size of the split pane based on its current size. **If the split pane is not correctly realized and on screen, this method will have no effect** (new divider location will become (current size * proportionalLocation) which is 0).

So it must be called ***after the GUI is visible.***

To achieve that during the process of *constructing* a GUI, I'd use a single shot Swing `Timer` that delays setting the divider location for around half a second, then start the timer at the end of creating the components.

### Implementation

Here is a simple implementation as an MCVE.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SplitPaneDivider {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    SplitPaneDivider() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        final JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                new ColoredPanel(Color.GREEN),
                new ColoredPanel(Color.YELLOW));
        ui.add(sp);
        ActionListener dividerListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sp.setDividerLocation(.7d);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(500, dividerListener);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    class ColoredPanel extends JPanel {

        ColoredPanel(Color color) {
            setBackground(color);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 100);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                SplitPaneDivider o = new SplitPaneDivider();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Split Pane Divider");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than setting a timer, you can also add a WindowListener to the JFrame and in `windowOpened` call `splitPane.setDividerLocation()`.

Comment: @AngerClown  That would not work for an applet, nor if the component with split pane is being created after the GUI is visible (e.g. when added as a new card to a `CardLayout` on button action).

Comment: See also the update, that shows an implementation of the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study the following to properly understand the workings of JSplitPane, and to get some demo examples:

[Oracle documentation on the use of JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html)